# VS2008 -> VS2010 RDLC stopped working when calling methods

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, rdlc

I used my VS2008 reports worked correctly. I migrated to VS2010 and my reports have stopped working.
Earlier I called methods of the TextBox directly from expressions like this:

```
=First(Fields!CteImpressao.Value.ObterValor("Number"))
```

or

```
=First(Code.AtribuirCte(Fields!CteImpressao.Value))
```

Now in VS2010 it generates #Error

Since the classes marked as serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has changed the way the reports are assembled, so you can no longer use the RDLC as was done in version VS2008.

Just generating a data source other way for my report funcionace correctly.